# Issue with converting MS Office files docx,ppt,xlsx to PDF using comtypes in Python on Mac-

Tags: python, pdf-generation, ms-office, comtypes

comtypes~=1.1.10 installation was successful on macOS Big Sur.

However I get the below error,
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ssn/Documents/GitHub/content-management-service/util/PPTtoPDF.py", line 3, in 
import comtypes.client
File "/Users/ssn/Documents/GitHub/content-management-service/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/comtypes/**init**.py", line 23, in 
from _ctypes import COMError
ImportError: cannot import name 'COMError' from '_ctypes' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-darwin.so)

Process finished with exit code 1

Can anyone help me fix this issue or is there any alternative for achieving the same?